# how to control all shop lights from one motion sensor shop light

Tags: electrical, lighting

So I recently replace a big 8 ft CCFL shop light with 3 smaller 4 ft shop lights.  1 has a motion sensor built in.  My thought when I bought them was to install the motion sensor might above the garage door, wire the hot and neutral coming from the switch to the motion sensor and then use the 2 prong outlet built into each light to connect the other two in series to each other.  Then I leave the switch on and all the lights come on when the motion sensor trips and turns off after the time out time.  In practice with the switch on the 2 normal shop lights stay on all the time and the motion sensor turns on and off as expected.   Here is the model shop light I'm using https://www.costco.com/Feit-4-ft.-Linkable-LED-Utility-Motion-Sensor-Shop-Lights,-2-pack.product.100415188.html

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, the fixtures are probably functioning as designed, and there's not much we could suggest that would help.

Answer (score 1):

Code requires that you use every device according to its labeling and instructions (because the testing behind the UL listing didn't test it any further than that).  So your first stop is back to the labeling and instructions on the lamp, and see what it says about using the receptacle to control other lights via the motion sensor.

Knowing Feit Electric, I suspect it *does not* permit that use, and the motion sensor does not switch the receptacle, and it is there to serve general loads like drills or trouble lights.   Or, their vision for this product is that you simply enable *all* the motion sensors and allow each light to decide independently.

I am no great fan of Feit's reliability and would not miss an opportunity to return a Feit to the store and get something quality. Generally everything electrical at CostCo is the pinnacle of Cheese junk.

If you really want to do motion sensor for the whole garage, they (not CostCo) sell individual "stalk" motion sensors, that screw into a junction box cover.  If you use the type which has a neutral wire, you can have 2 or more motion sensors for better coverage.  From those you power your lights.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspect the way I'll have to do this is to tear apart the motion sensor light and change how it feed power to the chained outlet it has.

Comment: @AdamAbel that's not allowed for a variety of reasons.  Not least, the motion sensor may not be rated for that much power, these things are built cheap. Also if these are integral LED lights, it is almost assuredly the case that the motion sensor is not 120V *at all*, and is on the LVDC side of the power supply. Most you could hope for is to hork in a relay, which would be better.