# outdoor ceiling light installation

Tags: light-fixture, outdoor, soffit

I had an older light fixture hanging above my garage door.  It stopped working, so I bought a replacement and went to install it.  When I removed the old light, I discovered that it had been screwed into a chunk of 2x4 which was just free-floating between the framing of the overhang and the steel soffit.  The hole is fairly small, but I went into the attic/crawlspace above the garage and couldn't see any light, so I think it's too small of a space (plus blown-in insulation) for me to come at it from above.  Further complicating the issue is that the new fixture seems to be expecting some kind of purpose built mounting plate or bracket of some kind which obviously doesn't exist.

I'm not a fan of this idea but I don't want to hire someone for hundreds of dollars to do this. So I'm thinking I can maybe just fake the funk again, here and cut away some of the soffit and maybe more-securely attach the wood chunk (or make a new wood chunk) and replicate the expected bracket that way.

Does this sound like a good idea and how would you solve the problem?

**edit**
Model:  Secure Home HeathZenith 022246

Comment: Not a good idea. If you post the model # of the new light we can (hopefully) verify how it is to be mounted, but most likely it is designed to be mounted on a standard junction box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a box in that location , an "old work" box can be placed into the hole and it will provide the mounts for the fixture. Old work boxes have tabs or wings that anchor to the back side of the wall.

Comment: Hopefully they have one that is only about 2 inches deep because that's literally all the space in that gap

Comment: I spoke to someone about the old work box and they were not optimistic about screwing the box into the wood panel above the soffit, alleging that I should build some sort of frame around it, to attach the box from the sides.  So that is slowing me down

Answer (score 0):

This mounts to a standard round ceiling box. It actually comes with a mounting bracket designed to screw onto a round ceiling box and the fixture attaches to that bracket. [Details in installation manual.](http://pdf.lowes.com/useandcareguides/016963430006_use.pdf)

Interesting feature: You can daisy chain to additional non-motion-sensing lights and have them all activate at the same time! That is a feature someone was looking for [with 4 ft. shop lights](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/151906/how-to-control-all-shop-lights-from-one-motion-sensor-shop-light). Right feature, wrong fixture.